# jquery filtering case insensitive

Tags: jquery, find, filtering

I found this filtering script:

[jsfiddle.net/Zhd2X/574/](http://jsfiddle.net/Zhd2X/574/)

Try to press **f** and **F** in first table - column boolean. In original version example was working only with **f** but I added *`.toLowerCase()`* in line no. 17.
But when you press **g** or **G** in second table - column speciality, filtering not working by my first update. I must to change line no. 18, but i dont have any idea...

Comment: Can you post the current script and the original one (before you made changes)? Even without the case issue it doesn't work properly. Also please consider [rewriting your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the text of the `<td>`s lowercase before filtering. Currently you're only making the value of the filter input lowercase.

```
var criteria = this.value.toLowerCase();

table.find(el).filter(function(_, td) {
    return $(td).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(criteria) == -1;
}).parent().hide();
```

#### [Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zhd2X/582/)

Answer (score 1):

You should create a case insensitive variant of the `:contains` JQuery selector, by adding the code below to your script. I named it `casecontains`.

```
jQuery.expr[':'].casecontains = function(a, i, m) { 
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0; 
};
```

After that, you can replace your line `17` with the following:

```
var criteria = ":casecontains('"+$(this).val()+"')";
```

Note that I just replaced `:contains` with `:casecontains`. Also, the conversion to lowercase is no longer needed.

[**Your updated fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zhd2X/585/)